# writing from to parquet using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

Trying to export and convert my data to a parquet file. Data is sba data from kaggle that we've transformed  bit. Trying to covert it to parquet to load onto a hfds server.

Data link
https://www.kaggle.com/mirbektoktogaraev/should-this-loan-be-approved-or-denied

[image]

[image]

tryin to use the code:

```
sba.to_parquet('sba.parquet.gzip', compression = 'gzip', partition_cols= 'State')
```

but get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-377ee6551e44> in <module>
----> 1 sba.to_parquet('sba.parquet.gzip', compression = 'gzip', partition_cols= 'State')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_parquet(self, path, engine, compression, index, partition_cols, storage_options, **kwargs)
   2453         from pandas.io.parquet import to_parquet
   2454 
-> 2455         return to_parquet(
   2456             self,
   2457             path,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py in to_parquet(df, path, engine, compression, index, storage_options, partition_cols, **kwargs)
    388     path_or_buf: FilePathOrBuffer = io.BytesIO() if path is None else path
    389 
--> 390     impl.write(
    391         df,
    392         path_or_buf,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py in write(self, df, path, compression, index, storage_options, partition_cols, **kwargs)
    150             from_pandas_kwargs["preserve_index"] = index
    151 
--> 152         table = self.api.Table.from_pandas(df, **from_pandas_kwargs)
    153 
    154         path_or_handle, handles, kwargs["filesystem"] = _get_path_or_handle(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_pandas()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in dataframe_to_arrays(df, schema, preserve_index, nthreads, columns, safe)
    600         for i, maybe_fut in enumerate(arrays):
    601             if isinstance(maybe_fut, futures.Future):
--> 602                 arrays[i] = maybe_fut.result()
    603 
    604     types = [x.type for x in arrays]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    430                 raise CancelledError()
    431             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 432                 return self.__get_result()
    433 
    434             self._condition.wait(timeout)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    386     def __get_result(self):
    387         if self._exception:
--> 388             raise self._exception
    389         else:
    390             return self._result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py in run(self)
     55 
     56         try:
---> 57             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     58         except BaseException as exc:
     59             self.future.set_exception(exc)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in convert_column(col, field)
    572             e.args += ("Conversion failed for column {!s} with type {!s}"
    573                        .format(col.name, col.dtype),)
--> 574             raise e
    575         if not field_nullable and result.null_count > 0:
    576             raise ValueError("Field {} was non-nullable but pandas column "

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in convert_column(col, field)
    566 
    567         try:
--> 568             result = pa.array(col, type=type_, from_pandas=True, safe=safe)
    569         except (pa.ArrowInvalid,
    570                 pa.ArrowNotImplementedError,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.array()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowInvalid: ('Could not convert 2004 with type str: tried to convert to int', 'Conversion failed for column ApprovalFY with type object')
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: It sounds like the "ApprovalFY" might have mixed type objects in it.  Converting to all the same type (int or string) should fix the problem.  More details on converation from [pandas to arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.from_pandas)

Answer (score 1):

@Micah Kornfield is correct. Here is more specific answer.
If you look at your data, more specifically between rows 688127 and 688128 you find the following

> df.loc[688127,'ApprovalFY']
> 2004

vs

> df.loc[688128,'ApprovalFY']
> '2004'

This type of change in data causes issue when parsing as parquet file. I am not an expert on parquet file, however the way that I understood is that parquet files identify the type of data in order to store them more efficiently. Therefore if you have a two different type of data in the same column you will receive the error. A lot of people run to this type of issue when they save their data into csv and then try to read csv file and concatenate the csv data with new data that they get from API,etc.
Every time you save your data in the csv format it converts it to text and when you read it it can change it from 2004 to '2004'.

Back to original question, it is a good idea to perform some data type checking before saving your data as parquet.